# Logback - get method name

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

We are currently migrating from log4j to Logback, but we are having problems obtaining the "original" method name that triggered the log.

I'm calling it "original" because we have a centralized logger class (to hide and manipulate certain logs) and what's showing up in the logs is the method name from that centralized class.

In log4j we were able to obtain the "original" method name correctly.

Is Logback able to obtain it or not?

**Loggers parameters**:

**log4j**

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p [%F] - %M() - %m%n"/>
```

**Logback**

```
<pattern>%d{"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS"} %-5level [%logger - %M] - %msg%n</pattern>
```

**Results: (Method Name - Class Name)**

**log4j**

```
doLogTester1 - a.Tester1            
doLogTester2 - b.Tester2            
doLogTester1 - a.Tester1            
doLogTester2 - b.Tester2
```

**Logback**

```
processLog - a.Tester1              
processLog - b.Tester2              
processLog - a.Tester1              
processLog - b.Tester2
```

**EDIT**
 - Full example

**Main.java**

```
public class Main
{
private static final LoggerCommon logger = new LoggerCommon(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        logger.doLog("I'm on the Main class in the main method");
    }
}
```

**LoggerCommon**

log4j

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggerCommon
{
    private static Logger logger;

    public LoggerCommon(Class<?> c)
    {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(c);
    }

    public void doLog(String message)
    {
        logger.log(LoggerCommon.class.getName(), Level.INFO, message, null);
    }
}
```

logback

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LoggerCommon
{
    private Logger logger;

    public LoggerCommon(Class<?> c)
    {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(c);
    }

    public void doLog(String message)
    {
        logger.info(message);
    }
}
```

**Config's**

log4j

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="CA" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%M - %F - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CA"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

logback

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="CA" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%M - %logger - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="CA"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In Log4j you are using `%M` which returns the calling method. I don't see how your Log4j could have coped with your centralized logging class any better than Logback does. Is this centralized logging class a new thing?

Comment: No, the centralized logger was in use for a long time now. When I saw this behavior in logback I checked some log4j logs to see if it was also happening but no.

Comment: The log4j documents warn against using M because "Generating caller location information is extremely slow and should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue."   In the past, when I've needed the method name from which I am logging a message, I include the method name in the text of the method.  for example, logging from the main method:  logger.info("main(); blah blah blah");

Comment: Please update your question to provide a little example code that will print the right method name in Log4j and the wrong method name in Logback. I'm still not convinced you'll achieve it with Log4j.

Comment: As requested just added the example

Comment: @Duncan Any ideas on how to implement the same logic with Logback?

Comment: @balizeiro Not currently. But thanks on providing an example - I hadn't believed you until then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using this:

```
methodName = stackTrace[xxxx].getMethodName();
```

Not perfect since xxxx varies based on server, but was the best we could found

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the 'caller data' is correct on the log event.

Probably one of these options will work:

Call ILoggingEvent::getCallerData() in your logger wrapper, to make sure the caller data is gathered early.

Maybe you can decorate the event in your centralised logger to spoof the caller data ILoggingEvent::getCallerData() call?

Or derive the caller data, then cast the ILoggingEvent to LoggingEvent, and call setCallerData() with you.

Comment: I'm new to logback and I'm not understanding what you mean by that. Could you please provide an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the logback source code, see how AsyncAppender does it.

Comment: Just looked into AsyncAppender.java and it's 4 methods: boolean isDiscardable(ILoggingEvent event), void preprocess(ILoggingEvent eventObject), boolean isIncludeCallerData(), void setIncludeCallerData(boolean includeCallerData) and I still don't understand how I can include it into my LoggerCommon.java

Comment: Most of the logic is in the base class.

Comment: BTW is there really a need to have your own log wrapper.  If you can just move to normal logging then it's a lot easier.

Comment: Still don't understand what you mean. Looked into  AsyncAppenderBase.java but still don't understand how I can incorporate it into my LoggerCommon.java. If you could provide an example I would appreciate it very much.
In regards of needing to have my own class it's because every log is logged I need to hide and manipulate certain logs.